# how can I work with the last element of iterations

Tags: c++, loops, cout

```
for(int t(0); t < 10;++t) { cout<<t<<endl;}
```

I'm just biginer in C++, and want to know how can I take the last elemnt of my "cout...."; in this case my laste element is 9

thx for help ;)

Comment: Excuse me, where are you taking that 9, mister? (your question is unclear).

Comment: you are missing `++t` for the last part, so your loop will never increase, and never end!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One simple way -

```
int t = 0;
for (; t < 10; ++t)
   cout << t << ;
```

Tough the correct way to do it will be (one variable should not have two meanings, i.e 1. last element, 2. iterator context) -

```
int last_element;
for (int t = 0; t < 10; ++t;
{
    cout << t << ;
    last_element = t;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract `int t` from the `for` loop :

```
int t;  
for (t = 0; t < 10; ++t)  
{
    cout << t << endl;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's 9 after the loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
int c = 0;
for(int t = 0; t<10; t++)
{
  c = t;
}
cout<<c;
```

This might be what you are looking for I am not sure I understand your question properly though.The variable c should hold the last element of t when the loop ends.

Answer (score 0):

```
int t = 9;
cout << t << endl;
```

Now you have the last element, #9.

Answer (score 0):

ghagha, in C++ the ranges are run from *0 to n-1*, in your example you have a range of 0 to < 10 hence 0 to 9, therefore your last element is 9.  But as I said you can do any range as *n-1* for the last element, provided that it follows normal conventions (it is possible to have a range from *1 to n* if you code it that way)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want but in any case your loop contains a bug. Instead of

```
for(int t(0); t < 10;  t) { cout<<t<<endl;}
```

should be

```
for(int t(0); t < 10;  t++) { cout<<t<<endl;}
```

that is variable t has to be incremented.

Comment: yup i just forget it ;)